# Sublime 3 open file using import route

Tags: routes, ide

I am looking for a sublime plugin that will allow me to open the file using a relative path, for example, I have:

```
import Switch from '../common/Switch'
```

I want to click on `../common/Switch` and get a new tab with this file, I know a lot of IDE can do that by default but can sublime do something like that?